# Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream. Android

Tags: php, android, json, mobile, pdo

It's almost 2days and I still can't figure it out.

I'm trying to get a data from the database using PDO(I'm noob here)
It's working on my localhost, but when I tried using an actual server, it's not working and i don't know why coz other file is working just fine and i used the same code, just edit some values

here's the java code

```
public class Attendance extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
Button btnSearch;
EditText searchField;
TextView tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, statVal, loginVal, logoutVal, accVal;
String stat,login,logout,acc;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
String username;
SessionManager session;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactsList;

//private static String url_search_attendance = "http://10.0.3.2/sunshine-ems/attendance_details.php";
private static String url_search_attendance = "http://www.sunshine-ems.balay-indang/mobile/attendance_details.php";
Button btnLogout;
final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attend);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    username = session.getUsername();
    //search editText
    searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }

    };
    searchField.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(Attendance.this, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

    //Logout Button
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);;
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching All products Activity
            session.logoutUser();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    //Hide TextViews
    instanciateAndHideTextViews();

    // Search Button
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);      
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new getAttendanceDetails().execute();
            displayTextViews();
        }
    });


}

private void instanciateAndHideTextViews(){

            tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            statVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statVal);
            loginVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginVal);
            logoutVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logoutVal);
            accVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accVal);

            tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tv5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            statVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loginVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            logoutVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            accVal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void displayTextViews(){
    tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    statVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    loginVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    logoutVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    accVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void updateLabel() {

    String myFormat = "yyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    searchField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    searchField.requestFocus();
    searchField.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}

private class getAttendanceDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Attendance.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading Attendance details");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("loading....");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                    params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", searchField.getText().toString().trim()));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_search_attendance, "GET", params1);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Details Attendance", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt("success");
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received attendance details
                        JSONArray jsonobj = json.getJSONArray("attendance_data"); // JSON Array

                        // get first object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject a_details = jsonobj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // Setter
                        stat = a_details.optString("status");
                        login = a_details.optString("login_time");
                        logout = a_details.optString("logout_time");
                        acc = a_details.optString("accumulated_time");

                    }else{

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonArray) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                statVal.setText(stat);
                loginVal.setText(login);
                logoutVal.setText(logout);
                accVal.setText(acc);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

}

here's the php code

```
  <?php 
require("config.php");
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {

$query = "
SELECT * FROM attendance
 where username= :username && date= :date";

$query_params = array(':username' => $_GET['username'],
                      ':date' => $_GET['date']
    );

//execute query
try {
    $stmt = $db-> prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt -> execute($query_params);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}  


// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt -> fetchAll();

if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";

    $response["attendance_data"] = array();

    foreach($rows as $row) {

        $a_data = array();
        $a_data["login_time"] = $row["login_time"];
        $a_data["logout_time"] = $row["logout_time"];
        $a_data["accumulated_time"] = $row["accumulated_time"];         
        $a_data["status"] = $row["status"];           


        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["attendance_data"], $a_data);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "You don't have appointment history.";
    die(json_encode($response));
}


}
?>
```

Here's the error log

```
02-04 10:17:06.986: E/Buffer Error(2920): Error converting result    java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
02-04 10:17:06.986: W/System.err(2920): org.json.JSONException: No value for attendance_data
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at com.example.androidtablayout.Attendance$getAttendanceDetails.doInBackground(Attendance.java:180)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at com.example.androidtablayout.Attendance$getAttendanceDetails.doInBackground(Attendance.java:1)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-04 10:17:06.990: W/System.err(2920):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-04 10:17:06.994: W/System.err(2920):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-04 10:17:06.994: W/System.err(2920):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

again, it's working on my localhost but not in the actual server. i hope someone can help me. thank you so much. I really need this tom

Comment: I got some error, when i tried catching an IOException , can u edit my code where to put that catch please?

Comment: Can you help me out here? i really need to finish this before morning, it's my thesis, I got the same error in my other classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a stream to read from.

```
java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
```

If it is working on your local host, but not with your server, it would appear that there is a problem with your url or your permissions to access your server. You are not working with an open stream. So check your url and your permissions. Ensure you are accessing your database, that you have the correct login details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, it seems that the url is incorrect. it doesn't have ".com" lol sorry about this